# can't trigger beforeunload event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onbeforeunload

I want to trigger the beforeunload event when the user clicks on the back button. I've set up event listeners for the beforeunload event, like so

```
useEffect(() => {
    const cb = (ev) => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      return (ev.returnValue =
        "Changes might not be saved. Are you sure you want to close?");
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", cb);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", cb);
  }, []);
```

Here's the code that detects when the back button is clicked:

```
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (history.action === "POP") {
        //ACTION TO BE DONE
        console.log("hoho", history.action);
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event("beforeunload"));
      }
    };
  });
```

When I click on the back button, I can see 'hoho POP' but the event is not being triggered. How can I fix this?

Comment: I would assume the removal of the event listener is unneeded, since the event will only run when the page is being reloaded. Try removing `return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", cb);` from the useEffect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intention was to show the popup about losing unsaved changes that shows up when the beforeunload event is triggered. Although I still can't manage to trigger the beforeunload event, I managed to figure out a workaround of sorts.

Instead of me triggering the event, I simply used the Prompt component of react router, like so:

```
<Prompt message="Leaving this page will cause you to lose unsaved data. Are you sure?" />
```

Refer to [react-router docs](https://%3CPrompt%20message=%22Leaving%20this%20page%20will%20cause%20you%20to%20lose%20unsaved%20data.%20Are%20you%20sure?%22%20/%3E) for more info on this component